# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare termSort() (previously declared in \includes\common.inc(1743) : eval()'d code on line 4

Tags: php, redeclare

Can you advise me please?

I have this code and I am displaying it on multiple pages (only with a changed VID). Everywhere, however, I leap above error.

How to modify this code so that it worked?

Thank you very much.

```
<?php
$vid = 4;
function termSort($a, $b) {return strcmp($a->name, $b->name);}
$terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);   usort ($terms,'termSort');
foreach ($terms as $term) {
if ($term->depth == 0) 
{  

print "" .l("<b>Flight  -&nbsp;</b> " .$term->name,'taxonomy/term/'.$term->tid, array('attributes' => array('title' => $term->name, ), 'html' => TRUE) ). "";


} 
}

?>
```

Comment: `... eval()'d code on line 4` -- why do you use `eval()` in the first place?

Comment: Error is pretty explanatory.. Remove your `function termSort()` from this code. As this function already exists on your common.inc.  Btw.. Amal Hi !!